# Android USB driver prolbem

Tags: android

I want to be able to run android apps I am developing in eclipse on my Samsung Galaxy S4. I followed the steps here... http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html and when I get to this part...

Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)

I get the following error message...

The folder you specified does not contain compatible driver software for your devise.
If the folder contains a driver make sure it is designed to work with windows x64-based systems.

I am running 64bit Windows 7 on a Lenovo thinkpad.  I recently installed the eclipse-ADK bundle.

Comment: i am not sure, but i think you need to install KIES for Samsung Phones to be able to connect

Answer (score 1):

you must just download samsung usb driver and instal it on device then restart adb and eclipse.
you can download samsung usb driver from below link

http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

good luck

Answer (score 1):

The Google driver is for Google devices, like the Nexus.
Galaxy S4 is not a Google device, it's a Samsung device. Therefore, you must download the Samsung driver: http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-
sdks/Samsung-Android-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Please do your research next time :)